# Intercept form submit via child of form?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a plugin using jQuery that modifies an input to give it a formatting mask when it is blurred, however I don't want to send through the formatted value when the form is submitted.

Is there a way I can intercept the parent forms submit event, adjust the value of the element to remove the mask, and then continue the submit without having to define it for every form that uses an input with the plugin?

The other option of course is to use a hidden input and store the raw value in that, and use the unnamed input to display the mask, but I would like to avoid extra markup if I can (plus it would be a handy trick!)

Comment: It is possible. Problem is making sure your handler would fire before any other user-binded handlers, e.g. a handler that prevent the default form submission and do it through Ajax.

Comment: Possibly a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647861/modify-post-vars-before-post-using-jquery

Comment: you could either prevent default on the submit button, reformat the field then submit the form using javascript or send the form as is and strip the formatting in whatever you are using to handle the submit. Do you need to do it pre form submission?

Comment: @KevPrice Well, the plugin is merely a cosmetic feature, so I would rather do it on the client-side where it is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#formid").submit(function(e){


    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the form from submitting

    var formatted_string = $("#formatted_input"); // get the formatted string you want to unformat

    var unformatted_string = formatted_string.replace(/regularexpression or string to be replaced/,'replacement string');  // use .replace() function to find and replace either a string or regular expression to undo your previous formatting

    $("#formatted_input").val(unformatted_string);       // set the input value as the new unformatted value

    $(this).submit(); //submit this form

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onsubmit` event of the form.
This event intercepts the forms submit event, letting you manipulate your data and even decide whether to submit the form or not (by its return code).

One common use case would be the validation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ValidateInput() {
  //validate something here
  return true; //true will submit the form, false will stop the submission here
}
</script>

<form action="yourfile.html" onsubmit="return ValidateInput();">
    ...
</form>
```

You can easily adapt this to manipulate your data.