# How to dynamically pass database value from one page to another using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to link a button to each of the database values, so when user clicks the button it transfers the information to another page. Currently I am like doing a hotel website where my first page is using a while loop to receive the rows in the database. Then because my images are not in the database, I use if to link the image to the values one by one. Similar to the price of the rooms.
As for moving the values from this page to the confirm page, I use the hidden input form to post my value to the next page. However, the value is not linked specifically to each of the button. No matter which button I click, I will receive the most bottom value. Is there any way I can do this?

This is a part of my code:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                
        echo "<h2>".$row["description"] . "</h2><br>";
                
        if ($row["description"] == "single room") {
            echo "<div class='row'>";
            echo "<div class='col'>";
            echo "<img src='images/single_room.jpg' 
                            alt='single room' 
                            width='500' 
                            height='200'<br>";
            echo "<div class='col'>";
            echo "<h3>$" . $row["price_per_night"] . "</h3><br>";
            echo "<form action='booking.php' method='post'>";
            echo "<div class='form-group'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='roomtype' value='single room'></div>";
            echo "<div class='form-group'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='price' value='".$row["price_per_night"]."'></div>";
            echo "<div class='form-group'>
                <button style='background-color:red' class='btn btn-primary' type='submit'>Book Room</button></div><br>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked your page source to see if you're generating valid html? Might be that your form tags aren't properly opened/closed.

Comment: I agree with EL_Vanja, it looks like <form> is not getting closed.

Comment: Yes the html is working fine, but just that I cannot dynamically bring the specific row information to the next page. It will just take the most bottom row value. I think it is because the names for the hidden input is all the same.

Comment: @cabbagebould Are you sure the form is getting closed? I don't see a </form> in your code

Comment: okay you guys are right omg.. thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try closing the form,

```php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                
        echo "<h2>".$row["description"] . "</h2><br>";
                
        if ($row["description"] == "single room") {
            echo "<div class='row'>";
            echo "<div class='col'>";
            echo "<img src='images/single_room.jpg' 
                            alt='single room' 
                            width='500' 
                            height='200'<br>";
            echo "<div class='col'>";
            echo "<h3>$" . $row["price_per_night"] . "</h3><br>";
            echo "<form action='booking.php' method='post'>";
            echo "<div class='form-group'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='roomtype' value='single room'></div>";
            echo "<div class='form-group'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='price' value='".$row["price_per_night"]."'></div>";
            echo "<div class='form-group'>
                <button style='background-color:red' class='btn btn-primary' type='submit'>Book Room</button></div><br>";
            echo "</form>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
```

Comment: omg.. it worked.. Thank you so much! At first I tot my method could not work. Could I ask if this is the method to do it. Because i feel like i am hardcoding this. I am lucky i only have 5 rows.

Comment: No worries, please consider marking my answer as accepted. This is not the cleanest way to do this although is a pure php html solution, you should look into javascript / jquery to post the data you would like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647861/modify-post-vars-before-post-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

use `$_SESSION` global variable to send data form one page to another taken from database. For example:
`$row = $result->fetch_assoc();  $_SESSION['row'] = $row;`

then, access the `$_SESSION` variable from any different page;
But keep in mind that you have to call `session_start()` function at the first line in both sender and receiver pages. thank you.

Comment: Is there a way that I can link each row's value to its specific buttons? I need to only transfer the specific row information based on which button the user clicks. Thank you

Comment: Yes, @cabbagebould, you can.

Answer (score 0):

On a second thought you may not need to use form and buttons, you can use simply use links.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            
    echo "<h2>".$row["description"] . "</h2><br>";
            
    if ($row["description"] == "single room") {
        echo "<div class='row'>";
        echo "<div class='col'>";
        echo "<img src='images/single_room.jpg' 
                        alt='single room' 
                        width='500' 
                        height='200'<br>";
        echo "<div class='col'>";
        echo "<h3>$" . $row["price_per_night"] . "</h3><br>";
        echo "<a href='view.php?room_id='".$row['id'].">view<>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

Then on the view.php page you will fetch the room info

```
$roomid = $_GET['room_id'];
```

do a query  with where roomid